# Healthy sitting while doing computer work

Tags: computers, ergonomics, posture, sitting, office

What are the most important things to look out for concerning regular sitting in front of a desktop computer?

Frankly, I don't know what's important and what I should prioritize.

- What chair should I choose? How much does it matter?
- Is it true that actively stabilizing one's posture, as opposed to using back-rests, arm-rests, or similar is healthier once you got used to it?
- How important is it to get up frequently; how often should I?
- Are there important tricks or routines I should apply to improve posture/health or encourage movement while sitting?

I'm interested in the first few points to know that make the biggest difference.

*Before tagging this as a duplicate, please note that it is not about a single posture or chair type, such as [this question on a single best posture](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/463) or [this one on exercise balls](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/811). My question isn't this narrow. If a great method were something like switching chair type halfway through the day, or to do a certain exercise every now and then, it would still be a valid answer.*

I'd be happy if answers include scientific evidence, or hints on how to search for it.

Comment: http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/463/whats-the-best-long-term-sitting-posture?lq=1 You may take a look the above link ..

Comment: @theinarasu I have already linked this in my question. In my opinion, the best answer is the one by nilon... and shows that the question is a tad narrow. I'm not limited to one posture or chair all day, or even just sitting all day. I opened a new question because I really want to focus on the heart of the issue, without limiting the approaches to only posture, or only chairs. I don't know what is most important, so that's part of the question.